# Clarification - Import statements in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a Spring web project.

I have a domain class:

```
com.ciar.seafac.engine.domain.Component
```

I am also using the `@Component` annotation from Spring framework:

```
org.springframework.stereotype.Component
```

I couldn't add import statements for both classes in my Class. So, I have to use fully qualified class name for my Component class.

Is there any other way to do this? May I know why Eclipse is not allowing me to import both classes? When i add both import statements and save the Class file. Eclipse just removes one. Please explain me why this happens.

Comment: FYI other languages have constructs to get around this e.g. Python has `import as` allowing you to give an alias to things that you import.

Comment: oh really, that's very nice. I just thought of anything like that in Java as well. that's why i just posted this question. It seems Java doesn't have it. Thanks blank for your information.

Comment: @Downvoter Can you please leave a comment? How can i improve my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If two classes have the exact same (simple) name you are going to have to fully qualify at least one of them. This is Java standard behavior, and documented in length [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html) (Chapter 7.5):

> If two single-type-import declarations in the same compilation unit attempt to import types with the same simple name, then a compile-time error occurs,

The automatism in Eclipse that leads to the removal of one of the imports is a "Save Action". These can be found in the Eclipse Settings:

```
Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions > "Organize Imports"
```

If you manually add two import statements and then fully qualify one of the classes, the corresponding import statement is redundant and therefore removed by "Organize Imports".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a fully qualified name inside your class for one of the `Components` then the import statement at the top for that one is redundant and eclipse will get rid of it (it's the  "Organize imports" option you can select as an on save action.

It's basically to make your code cleaner and smaller.